# Replace text according to table data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I want to write a program which replaces each specific letter by text according to data given in table.

```
create table jap (
alpha varchar2(1),
conv varchar2(5)
);

insert into jap(alpha,conv) values ( 'A' , 'ka' );
insert into jap(alpha,conv) values ( 'B' , 'tu' );
insert into jap(alpha,conv) values ( 'C' , 'mi' );
insert into jap(alpha,conv) values ( 'D' , 'te' );
insert into jap(alpha,conv) values ( 'E' , 'ku' );
insert into jap(alpha,conv) values ( 'F' , 'lu' );
insert into jap(alpha,conv) values ( 'G' , 'ji' );
```

For example, the input `DEC` should result in the output `tekumi`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT xmlagg(xmlelement(e, conv)
              ORDER BY l).extract('//text()') .getstringval()
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT LEVEL l,
                         substr('DEC', LEVEL, 1) letter
   FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= length('DEC'))
INNER JOIN jap ON alpha = letter
ORDER BY l ;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/afa7e/43) is a fiddle

Comment: friends i had tried but ur code is not working . thanksalot for ur time.

Comment: Maybe something more than "it's not working" would be helpful? I've had a quick look in the SQL Fiddle and it seems to run, except the letters come out in the wrong order ('metiku' instead of 'tekumi'). Probably only a simple fix needed.

Comment: This code worked for me.  If it doesn't work for you it is probably an mistake you have made (typo or something).  In any case you need to give us more details, explaing *how* it doesn't work, including any error message, if you expect somebody to help you further.

Comment: Thanks @MikeMeyers, Apparently the `xmlagg` function has a `order by` clause that solves this problem

Comment: WHEN 
SELECT xmlagg(xmlelement(e, conv)
              ORDER BY l).extract('//text()') .getstringval()
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT LEVEL l,
                         substr('DEC', LEVEL, 1) letter
   FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= length('DEC'))
INNER JOIN jap ON alpha = letter
ORDER BY l ;
tekumi
/***

 SELECT xmlagg(xmlelement(e, conv)
               ORDER BY l).extract('//text()') .getstringval()
 FROM
   (SELECT DISTINCT LEVEL l,
                          substr('DEC', LEVEL, 1) letter
    FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= length('march'))
 INNER JOIN jap ON alpha = letter
 ORDER BY l
 /

tekumi

Comment: what ever i put the input i got the same answer

Comment: thank alot for ur response  i had written the procedure and it is working write thank u

Comment: @GirishRAcharya, that's because you had to replace the constant `DEC` in both places (in the `substr` and in the `length`) if you'll use it with a parameter, you'll need to put it in both cases. A single sql may be faster then a plsql SP